# Alternative to WP Remote - manage multiple WP sites in a dashboard (updates, plugins...)

Tags: management

Do you know of a (possibly free) alternative to [WP Remote](https://wpremote.com/)?

It would be handy to have a dashboard to manage many Wordpress installations across multiple domains.

They have no privacy policy, privacy gaurantee, or terms of use in any form on their website; and I'm not keen to jump on their bandwagon if they have no 'service gaurantees'.

Comment: Any reason to not consider using multisite?

Comment: I have 3 multi site installations on 3 different domains, plus single installs on others. Are you suggesting using domain mapping with multi site. I have considered this, but it may not be possible for subdomains across multiple domains.

Comment: There are two solid options for using multiple domains in one install -- the domain mapping plugin, as you suggested, and the multi network plugin. I prefer to use domain mapping, and it works like a champ for me. I have many subdomains across many domains, and everything works perfect. I've tried every conceivable workflow over the past 6 years for running multiple WordPress sites and I'm convinced that multisite and domain mapping is the best in every way.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes: Hi Matt.  I used to have 1 subdomain Wordpress network in www.example.com, and 1 subdirectory Wordpress network in www.example.com/test/.  I used the latter for development websites.  A few months ago I took it all down, and I have recently put it all back up.  However, I have added domain mapping to the first network, and now the second network's subsites will not load; www.example.com/test/site1 displays a 404 error from www.example.com, even though there is an .htaccess file in www.example.com/test/ and I can load www.example.com/test/wp-admin.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We have added a [privacy](https://wpremote.com/privacy-policy/) and [security](https://wpremote.com/security/) policy fairly recently, so do take a look.

We do take all your concerns very seriously, so if you have any further questions do not hesitate to get in touch with us.

Answer (score 0):

I have been pretty happy with ManageWP for the last few months of use.

It's not free, but I think it works well and I think the prices are reasonable. The cost depends on a combination of number of sites you manage and the feature set you want.